# Dynamic deserialize Json in Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq

How to make it work? I don't know the type of Details but I know it has a color field.

```
categories.Where(x => ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x.Details)).Color.Equals(controllerName));
```

compile time error says: "an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Comment: Serialize it into an actual object model. Is `categories` a database object? Then you need to save `.Color` into a variable. You should probably do that anyway as otherwise you are deserializing on every execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with JObject

```
categories.Where(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(x.Details)["Color"] == controllerName);
```

if `categories` is JArray then you don't need to deserialize also.